# React.js, JavaScript Get Img by clicking a parent element from an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a select component which works as a navigation.

When I click one of menu list, the clickedValue(img and text) should be on the button element.

I found a way to show clicked text value which is "e.currentTarget.textContent" but for the img, I cannot find a way...

I've tried innerHTML which show me literally link source, but not actual image.

I didn't write some other codes that you don't need, if that bothers you, sorry xD

```
state = {
   clickedValue : 'cryptocurrency'
}


handleSelected = (e) => {
    const { clickedValue } = this.state;

    this.setState({
        clickedValue : e.currentTarget.textContent
    })
}

const menu = [{
        link : '/service',
        img : some link,
        title : 'Cryptocurrency'
    },{
        link : '/service/wallet',
        img : some link2,
        title : 'Wallet'
    }, {
        link : '/service/ico',
        img : some link3,
        title : 'Ico'
    }]

<button>Clicked Value which is img and text here</button>
{menu.map(
    (menu) => (
         <li onClick={handleSelected} className={cx('list')}><NavLink exact to={menu.link}><img src={menu.img} alt={menu.title}/>{menu.title}</NavLink></li>
    )
)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you could make it work the way you are intending, but why not simply pass the menu value to `handleSelected`?

`<li onClick={() => this.handleSelected(menu)}`

Saves a lot of time for you :)

Comment: Also a side note: Best practice is to not reuse your mapping variable name, it causes confusion :P

e.g `menu.map(menu => {})` < `menu.map(menuItem => {})`

Comment: Hey Tom! Thanks for the tip! I mapped those because there are some same attributes, elements in the <li></li> didnt want to write these over and over again. and You're so right about the mapping variable name!  thank you!

Comment: back to the topic, when i write `<li onClick={() => this.handleSelected(menu)}`, How can i get img from the clicked <li></li>??

Comment: Onclick your `handleSelected()` function will receive the menu item object:

{
        link : '/service',
        img : some link,
        title : 'Cryptocurrency'
    }

So you can work with that easily, just update your function to do `e.img` or something